# Consulta MySQL, de Filas a Columnas

Tags: mysql, pivot

Quisiera dar formato a mi consulta de tal manera que la tabla me quede de esta manera.
[image]

Comment: Hola EDU, si colocas que has intentado hacer me va a ser más fácil ayudar ya que podríamos partir desde la lógica que has aplicado. Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

La forma en la que se puede obtener el resultado deseado es mediante un procedimiento que genere una tabla temporal con columnas y registros creados de manera dinámica a partir de una consulta SQL.

En resumen, el procedimiento que vamos a crear va a realizar lo siguiente:

- `Crear una Tabla temporal`: almacenará los registros en columnas.
- `Columnas`: las columnas de la tabla temporal serán generados de forma dinámica según la consulta.
- `INSERT INTO` dinámico para llenar la tabla temporal.
- `Consulta a la tabla temporal`: al final del procedimiento consultaremos la tabla temporal creada que devolverá un `result set`.

A continuación los pasos a realizar para obtener el resultado en formato pivot, se puede modificar el procedimiento para adaptarlo a la estructura de tu base de datos.

**Primer Paso:**

Crear una tabla llamada registros para simular la primera tabla de la imagen:

```
CREATE TABLE registros
  (
     id_cita          INT,
     codigo_item      VARCHAR(15),
     tipo_diagnostico VARCHAR(1),
     valor_lab        VARCHAR(5)
  );
```

**Segundo Paso:**

Insertar algunos registros para testear el resultado:

```
INSERT INTO `registros` (
    `id_cita`, 
    `codigo_item`, 
    `tipo_diagnostico`, 
    `valor_lab`
) 
VALUES
    (309701329, 'Z359', 'D', '1'),
    (309701329, '99401.33', 'D', '1'),
    (309701329, '86703', 'D', 'RN'),
    (309701329, '99401.34', 'D', '1'),
    (309701329, '86780', 'D', 'RN'),
    (309701329, '99402.05', 'D', '1'),
    (309849852, 'K021', 'D', '1'),
    (123465461, 'K991', 'D', 'RN');
```

**Tercer Paso:**

Crear el procedimiento que se encarga de generar el pivot:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_registros_pivot`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE finishedRows INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    -- Declaramos la variable que almacenará el DDL de 
    -- la tabla temporal.
    DECLARE vSqlDDL     VARCHAR(1500) DEFAULT '';
    -- Variable que almacenará las columnas que serán 
    -- dinámicas.
    DECLARE vSqlColumns VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '';
    -- Cantidad de columnas que necesitamos crear
    DECLARE vColumnCount INT;
    -- Iterador, auxiliar para los loops 
    DECLARE i INT;
    -- Almancena el id de la cita en el recorrido del loop
    DECLARE vRow INT;
    -- Cantidad de values que va a tener una cita
    DECLARE vRowCount INT;
    -- Auxiliares para almacenar sql generado dinamicamente
    DECLARE vSQLInsert VARCHAR(1500) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE vSQLInsertCol VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE vSQLValues VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '';

    -- Cursor para recorrer las citas agrupado por id_cita
    DECLARE curRows CURSOR FOR
        SELECT id_cita, count(*) 
        FROM registros
        GROUP BY id_cita;

    -- Manejador de NOT FOUND para salir del blucle cuando 
    -- ya no queden registros por recuperar.
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
        FOR NOT FOUND SET finishedRows = 1;

    -- Averiguamos la cantidad de columnas dinamicas
    -- a crear.
    SELECT Max( c )
    INTO   vColumnCount
    FROM  ( SELECT Count( * ) c
            FROM   registros
            GROUP  BY id_cita ) AS q;

    -- Generamos la tabla temporal 
    SET i = 1;
    WHILE i <= vColumnCount DO
        SET vSqlColumns = CONCAT(vSqlColumns, ' codigo_item_it',i,' VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT NULL, ');
        SET vSqlColumns = CONCAT(vSqlColumns, ' tipo_diagnostico_it',i,' VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL, ');
        SET vSqlColumns = CONCAT(vSqlColumns, ' valor_lab_it',i,' VARCHAR(5) DEFAULT NULL,');
        SET i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS registros_pivot;
    SET vSqlDDL = CONCAT(
        'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE registros_pivot (id_cita INT,', 
        SUBSTR(vSqlColumns, 1, CHARACTER_LENGTH(vSqlColumns)-1), ')'
    );

    SET @vSQLEx = vSqlDDL;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @vSQLEx;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    -- fin generación de tabla temporal

    -- Recorremos las citas con la cantidad de
    -- repeticiones de id_cita
    OPEN curRows;
    getRows: LOOP
        FETCH curRows INTO vRow, vRowCount;

        IF finishedRows = 1 THEN 
            LEAVE getRows;
        END IF;

        -- Limpiamos las variables auxiliares que almacena 
        -- el sql dinámico
        SET vSQLInsert = '';
        SET vSQLValues = '';
        SET vSQLInsertCol  = '';

        -- Generamos las columnas para el insert
        SET i = 1;
        SET vSQLInsertCol = CONCAT(vSQLInsertCol, ' id_cita,');
        WHILE i <= vRowCount DO
            SET vSQLInsertCol = CONCAT(vSQLInsertCol, ' codigo_item_it',i, ',');
            SET vSQLInsertCol = CONCAT(vSQLInsertCol, ' tipo_diagnostico_it',i, ',');
            SET vSQLInsertCol = CONCAT(vSQLInsertCol, ' valor_lab_it',i,',');
            SET i = i + 1;
        END WHILE;

        -- Quitamos la última coma.
        SET vSQLInsertCol = SUBSTR(vSQLInsertCol, 1, CHARACTER_LENGTH(vSQLInsertCol)-1);

        -- Generamos el sql para el Insert
        SET vSQLInsert = CONCAT(
            vSQLInsert,
            'INSERT INTO registros_pivot (',
            vSQLInsertCol,
            ') VALUES(', 
            vRow,
            ','
         );         
        -- 

        -- Generamos los values para el insert
        BVALUES: BEGIN
            DECLARE finishedValues   INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
            -- Variables que serán utilizados para la recuperar
            -- datos del cursor.
            DECLARE vCodigoItem      VARCHAR(15);
            DECLARE vTipoDiagnostico VARCHAR(1);
            DECLARE vValorLab        VARCHAR(5);

            -- Cursor que consulta los registros en donde aparece
            -- id_cita. 
            DECLARE cursorValues CURSOR FOR
                SELECT codigo_item, tipo_diagnostico, valor_lab
                FROM registros
                WHERE id_cita = vRow;

            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
                FOR NOT FOUND SET finishedValues = 1;

            OPEN cursorValues;

            getValue: LOOP
                FETCH cursorValues INTO vCodigoItem, vTipoDiagnostico, vValorLab;
                IF finishedValues = 1 THEN 
                    LEAVE getValue;
                END IF;
                -- Generamos los values 
                SET vSQLValues = CONCAT(
                    vSQLValues,
                    '''', IFNULL(vCodigoItem, ''), '''', ',',
                    '''', IFNULL(vTipoDiagnostico, ''), '''', ',',
                    '''', IFNULL(vValorLab, ''), '''', ','
                );

            END LOOP getValue;
            CLOSE cursorValues;
        END BVALUES;

        -- Quitamos la última coma
        SET vSQLValues = SUBSTR(vSQLValues, 1, CHARACTER_LENGTH(vSQLValues)-1);   

        SET @vSQLEx = CONCAT(vSQLInsert, vSQLValues, ')');
        -- ejecutamos el insert.
        PREPARE stmt FROM @vSQLEx;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;     

        END LOOP getRows;
    CLOSE curRows;

    -- consultamos la tabla temporal que devolverá los datos con el formato deseado
    SELECT * FROM registros_pivot;
END
//
```

**Resultado:**

Probar el resultado (Para consultar, llamar al procedimiento de la siguiente manera):

```
call sp_registros_pivot();
```

Resultado:

```
id_cita   |codigo_item_it1 |tipo_diagnostico_it1 |valor_lab_it1 |codigo_item_it2 |tipo_diagnostico_it2 |valor_lab_it2 |codigo_item_it3 |tipo_diagnostico_it3 |valor_lab_it3 |codigo_item_it4 |tipo_diagnostico_it4 |valor_lab_it4 |codigo_item_it5 |tipo_diagnostico_it5 |valor_lab_it5 |codigo_item_it6 |tipo_diagnostico_it6 |valor_lab_it6 |
----------|----------------|---------------------|--------------|----------------|---------------------|--------------|----------------|---------------------|--------------|----------------|---------------------|--------------|----------------|---------------------|--------------|----------------|---------------------|--------------|
123465461 |K991            |D                    |RN            |                |                     |              |                |                     |              |                |                     |              |                |                     |              |                |                     |              |
309701329 |Z359            |D                    |1             |99401.33        |D                    |1             |86703           |D                    |RN            |99401.34        |D                    |1             |86780           |D                    |RN            |99402.05        |D                    |1             |
309849852 |K021            |D                    |1             |                |                     |              |                |                     |              |                |                     |              |                |                     |              |                |                     |              |
```