# Consulta de filas a columnas

Tags: mysql, subconsultas

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La semana varía dependiendo a la semana del año.

Obtengo con un `SUM(tiempo_real)`, la suma por semana de cada ingeniero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema viene cuando quiero poner las columnas de la suma de todas semanas del año, ya que al aumentar las columnas me trae la suma total de la semana para cada técnico:

```
SELECT tecnico, (SELECT SUM(tiempo_real) FROM despacho WHERE semana= 26) as sem26, (SELECT SUM(tiempo_real) FROM despacho WHERE semana= 27) as sem27 FROM despacho GROUP by tecnico
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado al que quiero llegar es ese:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias y saludos.

Comment: Parece un duplicado en intención de está https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309320/consulta-mysql-de-filas-a-columnas

Comment: @Aprendiz gracias por la observación, intentare construir el Store a mis necesidades.

Comment: Si al momento de construirlo tienes problemas edita tu pregunta por favor con esos detalles