# Tabla de frecuencias de situacionlaboral por localidad MySQL

Tags: mysql

tengo la siguiente tabla en MySQL (solamente trabajo con localidad y situacionlaboral)

```
 LOCALIDAD  SITUACIONLABORAL
     5      Parado          
     4      Activo          
     4      Estudiante      
     1      Parado          
     6      Activo          
     1      Jubilado        
     5      Activo          
     2      Activo          
    11      Activo          
     3      Activo          
     5      Estudiante      
     4      Jubilado        
     1      Parado          
     7      Activo          
     9      Parado          
     9      Activo          
     9      Activo
```

Y tengo que determinar un "conteo de frecuencias" por localidad, teniendo que tener como salida el siguiente formato:

```
LOCALIDAD TOTAL PARADOS ACTIVOS JUBILADOS ESTUDIANTES
     1      3      2       0        1        
     2      1      0       1        0
     3      1      0       1        0        [...]
     4      3      0       1        1
     5      3      1       1        0
                  [...]
```

He intentado un par de soluciones, pero sin resultado ya que el COUNT no muestra 0 en el caso de que haya una localidad sin alguna de las diferentes situaciones laborales, y en el caso del JOIN se eliminarían filas.

El script para la creación sería el siguiente:

```
create table votantes
    (dni number(8) primary key,
    nombreCompleto varchar2(64),
    estudiosSuperiores varchar2(16) not null,
    situacionLaboral varchar2(16) not null,
    email varchar2(32) not null,
    localidad number(3) not null,
    fechaNacimiento date not null,
    telefono number(14),
    constraint ck_estudios CHECK (estudiosSuperiores in ('Ninguno','Basicos','Superiores','Doctorado')),
    constraint ck_laboral CHECK (situacionLaboral in ('Estudiante','Jubilado','Parado','Activo')),
    constraint fk_localidad_vot foreign key (localidad) references localidades(idLocalidad));
```

Y aquí algunos inserts:

```
insert into votantes
values (30983712, 'Jose Perez Perez', 'Basicos', 'Parado','jpp@gmail.com',5,'23/02/1982',662234293);
insert into votantes
values (41867538, 'Laura Valenzuela Ferrer', 'Doctorado', 'Activo','lavafe@gmail.com',4,'09/09/1975',722657395);
insert into votantes
values (44826745, 'Pedro Jimenez Santos', 'Basicos', 'Estudiante','jimsanped@yahoo.es',4,'12/09/1997',625336491);
insert into votantes
values (30725352, 'Marta Sanchez Rodriguez', 'Ninguno', 'Parado','martita00@hotmail.com',1,'28/01/2000',654825492);
insert into votantes
values (45245264, 'Ana María Expósito Escudero', 'Superiores', 'Activo','expositoeam@yahoo.es',6,'30/07/1992',692547885);
insert into votantes
values (31075940, 'Alberto Nuñez Fernandez', 'Basicos', 'Jubilado','anfernandez@outlook.com',1,'14/05/1950',666350983);
insert into votantes
values (45374737, 'Carolina Lopez Muriel', 'Basicos', 'Activo','karolop90@hotmail.com',5,'19/11/1988',643176224);
insert into votantes
values (30852845, 'Pablo Morales Raigan', 'Doctorado', 'Activo','morapa@telefonica.es',2,'25/03/1969',677534816);
insert into votantes
values (45628436, 'Manuel Medina Alvarez', 'Superiores', 'Activo','manuelmedinalv@gmail.com',11,'01/01/1992',625826487);
insert into votantes
values (31087814, 'Luisa Cano Vega', 'Ninguno', 'Activo','louisecave@yahoo.es',3,'05/06/1981',645623736);
insert into votantes
values (45657294, 'Alvaro Diaz Gomez', 'Basicos', 'Estudiante','alvadigo@ono.es',5,'29/08/1999',757427827);
insert into votantes
values (08727847, 'Estrella Ortiz Mengual', 'Superiores', 'Jubilado','esomen@gmail.com',4,'23/01/1953',611892544);
insert into votantes
values (75648104, 'Hector Mendoza Hernandez', 'Doctorado', 'Parado','he2men@yahoo.es',1,'14/10/1986',654264027);
insert into votantes
values (80762946, 'Andres Carrasco Cruz', 'Basicos', 'Activo','andrescaracruz@yahoo.es',7,'11/09/1992',699427546);
insert into votantes
values (30559073, 'Lucia Hoyos Martin', 'Basicos', 'Parado','hoyosmalu@hotmail.com',9,'31/03/1998',721988562);
insert into votantes
values (30559074, 'Martin Hoyos Martin', 'Basicos', 'Activo','hoyosmama@hotmail.com',9,'01/03/1996',721988563);
insert into votantes
values (30559075, 'Jose Hoyos Martin', 'Superiores', 'Activo','hoyosmaj@hotmail.com',9,'22/01/1993',721988560);
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tu pregunta debe contener lo que intentaste.. Esos datos que estas mostrando, no son reales no?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Consulta MySQL, de Filas a Columnas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309320/consulta-mysql-de-filas-a-columnas)

Comment: Chicos porfa antes de arreglar algo en esta consulta, esos datos parecen reales!

Comment: gbianchi, no son datos reales, son datos de ejemplo de unas prácticas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más simple de totalizar horizontalmente es haciendo un `count` selectivo a partir de una sentencia `CASE`, la idea sería:

```
 SELECT localidad,
        COUNT(1) Total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  situacionLaboral = 'Estudiante' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Estudiante,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  situacionLaboral = 'Jubilado' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Jubilado,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  situacionLaboral = 'Parado' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Parado,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN  situacionLaboral = 'Activo' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS Activo
        FROM votantes
        GROUP BY localidad
        ORDER BY localidad
```

Salida:

```
| LOCALIDAD | TOTAL | ESTUDIANTE | JUBILADO | PARADO | ACTIVO |
|-----------|-------|------------|----------|--------|--------|
|         1 |     3 |          0 |        1 |      2 |      0 |
|         2 |     1 |          0 |        0 |      0 |      1 |
|         3 |     1 |          0 |        0 |      0 |      1 |
|         4 |     3 |          1 |        1 |      0 |      1 |
|         5 |     3 |          1 |        0 |      1 |      1 |
|         6 |     1 |          0 |        0 |      0 |      1 |
|         7 |     1 |          0 |        0 |      0 |      1 |
|         9 |     3 |          0 |        0 |      1 |      2 |
|        11 |     1 |          0 |        0 |      0 |      1 |
```

**Nota**: Si te haces la pregunta ¿Y si tuviera muchos estados más o los mismos fueran creciendo con el tiempo? lamentablemente, la transposición de una consulta "vertical" a un a "horizontal" tiene limitaciones, una de ellas es que no se puede ajustar dinámicamente las columnas, por que el propio lenguaje no lo permite, tienes que conocer de antemano las columnas que vas a usar. Para hacerlo dinámico deberías construir una sentencia `SQL` como la que te presenté a partir la lista de estados que tuvieras.

Comment: Gracias, esta resuelve el problema por completo. Y con respecto a lo que comentas, si, puede ser un problema en situaciones de mayor envergadura, pero en este caso ha sido una prueba un tanto extraña y poco común. 

Gracias y un saludo !!