# Pivotar tabla con N columnas

Tags: mysql, group-by, pivot

Tras resolver este problema en PHP con varios bucles y en SQL haciendo uso de una tabla auxiliar y varios querys para ir ampliándola, me he quedado con la duda de si se podría haber resuelto con una simple consulta.

El dataset de partida sería algo así:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla(
  fila int,
  columna int,
  dato int
  );
INSERT INTO tabla (fila, columna, dato) VALUES
  (1,1,1),(1,2,2),(1,3,3),(2,1,4),(2,2,5),
  (3,1,6),(4,2,7),(4,3,8),(5,1,9),(6,2,10);
```

La tabla tendría este aspecto:

```
#   f   c   dato
-   -   -   -
1   1   1   1
2   1   2   2
3   1   3   3
4   2   1   4
5   2   2   5
6   3   1   6
7   4   2   7
8   4   3   8
9   5   1   9
10  6   2   10
```

Y quiero llegar a algo así:

```
#   f   c1  c2  c3
1   1   1   2   3
2   2   4   5   
3   3   6   
4   4       7   8
5   5   9   
6   6       10
```

Para N=3 he utilizado esta consulta:

```
SELECT fila,
  SUM(IF(columna=1,dato,NULL)) c1,
  SUM(IF(columna=2,dato,NULL)) c2,
  SUM(IF(columna=3,dato,NULL)) c3
  FROM tabla GROUP BY 1;
```

Y la pregunta es: ¿Existe alguna forma de que muestre tantas columnas como valores diferentes tome el campo `columna` sin tener que ajustar la query manualmente? Algo similar a:

```
SELECT fila,
  GROUP_CONCAT(dato) columnas
  FROM tabla GROUP BY 1;
```

Pero en diferentes campos, en vez de uno único y separando los contenidos por comas.

Adjunto la solución más sencilla que he encontrado hasta el momento, construyendo la consulta dinámicamente desde un lenguaje de programación externo, en este caso PHP:

```
<?php
$conn=new mysqli('localhost','root','','stackoverflow');
$rs=$conn->query("
    SELECT DISTINCT columna FROM tabla;
");
while($ri=$rs->fetch_row())
    $cols[]=$ri[0];
$cs=null;
foreach($cols as $c)
    $cs.=",SUM(IF(columna='".$c."',dato,NULL)) c".$c;
$rs=$conn->query("
    SELECT fila".$cs."
      FROM tabla GROUP BY 1;
")->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($rs);
echo '</pre>';
```

Todas las soluciones que me han sugerido hasta el momento están basadas en esta misma idea. Lo que puede significar que tal vez no haya una forma más sencilla de resolverla. No considero que la pregunta esté duplicada porque busco la generalización a N columnas y no el caso particular que responde la propia pregunta.

Comment: Esto quizas te ayude: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78 (en ingles). Aqui tienes tambien un ejemplo de query para el mismo problema: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/how-can-i-return-pivot-table-output-in-mysql

Comment: Gracias @PabloCG, justo hasta ahí es a donde he conseguido llegar. Pero imagínate que tienes 100 columnas, ¿habría algo similar al `GROUP_CONCAT()` que te permitiera separar en columnas?

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero posiblemente no quede otra opción que crear alguna query dinámica, donde el CONCAT seria sobre el string, y luego la ejecutarias segun el caso. No exactamente para pivot, pero aqui una idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178816/mysql-dynamic-query-in-stored-procedure

Comment: Efectivamente, con una query dinámica desde PHP también he conseguido que quede bastante compacto. Lo ideal sería un `GROUP_COLUMN()` o algo similar que evite tener que programarlo.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Consulta MySQL, de Filas a Columnas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/309320/consulta-mysql-de-filas-a-columnas)

Comment: Gracias @BetaM, pero no, ya lo sineto, busco una solución más compacta y sencilla... voy a ampliar la pregunta con la solución que he encontrado apoyándome en una query dinámica desde PHP para ilustrar la idea. Gracias nuevamente por echarle un vistazo